# Cannot insert content script into apps.facebook.com pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension, facebook-apps, content-script

I want to insert a js file into a webpage using chrome extension. So I wrote this code into the manifest file:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://apps.facebook.com/frivacy/*", "http://apps.facebook.com/frivacy/"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "catch.js"]
    }
  ]
```

The problem is that it cannot insert any script into these pages. I tried with other pages, and the same code is able to insert scripts in those pages...but particularly not this one. Why ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...solved the issue...so the thing is that facebook was putting all my codes inside an iframe....so i just changed one line chrome manifest and it was working...

in the content script section, add this:
"all_frames": true

so this inserts the javascript code into all frames and it is now working...thanks though.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a trailing `*` for the match pattern `"http://apps.facebook.com/frivacy/*"` and let me know if it  still fails.

Comment: I tried that...it fails...from what I have researched, I know that facebook inserts its own code...so it kind of replaces my code...so my chrome extension is not able to find any element...because its been changed by FB....I may be wrong...but its my best guess...

Comment: yes I am sure of what I said...facebook apps is putting all my codes inside one frame...so the question is that:
my chrome content script looks for a particular element (#launch) inside a page...but when this page is loaded in facebook apps...this element is kept inside another frame...so now that being said..what would be the equivalent code for this:
$("#launch").click(funtion() {alert("hi")});